# Why dynamically allocated buffer in user program makes kernel driver crash?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, driver, kernel

I have a program that allocates a buffer whose pointer is passed to a kernel driver through a custom IOCTL. In the driver I get an Mdl and lock the pages of the user-program buffer with "MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe" and then use the Mdl to fill the user program buffer.

If in the user program the buffer was a normal array, the driver always works as it should.
(WORD buffer[256], where word is an unsigned short)

If the user program buffer was instead allocated with the new keyword `(WORD *buffer = new WORD[256])` or the malloc keyword `(WORD *buffer=(WORD*) malloc(sizeof(*buffer)*256)))` from time to time I get a BSOD and the error is "page fault in non paged area".

WHY?

Thanks!

EDIT(additional details):

In the driver I use `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` this way:

`PVOID p_buffer = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Irp->MdlAddress, HighPagePriority);`

Irp is a PIRP that I receive as the second parameter when I handle the `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL` MajorFunction.

After I've checked that `p_buffer` is not null, I use that pointer to write user buffer:

`READ_PORT_BUFFER_USHORT((PUSHORT)(USHORT)current_port.address, (PUSHORT)p_buffer, 256)`

IOCTL definition:

```
#define IOCTL_TEST_READPORT      CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_TEST,  \
    TEST_IOCTL_INDEX + 0,   \
    METHOD_OUT_DIRECT,         \
    FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

Driver function that handles `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL`:

```
    NTSTATUS TESTDispatch(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpStack;
ULONG              input_buffer_size;
ULONG              output_buffer_size;
ULONG              control_code;
PVOID              p_buffer;
NTSTATUS           nt_status;
struct             port current_port;

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);
PAGED_CODE();

Irp->IoStatus.Status      = STATUS_SUCCESS;
Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

IrpStack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

switch (IrpStack->MajorFunction)
{

case IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL:

    control_code = IrpStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode;

    switch (control_code)
    {
        case IOCTL_TEST_READPORT:
            p_buffer = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Irp->MdlAddress, HighPagePriority);
            input_buffer_size  = IrpStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength;

            if (!p_buffer) 
            {
                nt_status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                break;
            }
            if (input_buffer_size)
            {
                memcpy (&current_port, Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, input_buffer_size);
                switch (current_port.size)
                {
                case 1:
                    current_port.value = (ULONG)READ_PORT_UCHAR((PUCHAR)(USHORT)current_port.address);
                    memcpy (p_buffer, &current_port.value, sizeof(current_port.value));
                    Irp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(current_port.value);
                    break;
                case 0xF0:
                    READ_PORT_BUFFER_USHORT((PUSHORT)(USHORT)current_port.address, (PUSHORT)p_buffer, 256);
                    Irp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(current_port.value);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    current_port.value = (ULONG)READ_PORT_USHORT((PUSHORT)(USHORT)current_port.address);
                    memcpy (p_buffer, &current_port.value, sizeof(current_port.value));
                    Irp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(current_port.value);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                break;
        case IRP_MJ_CREATE:
            KdPrint(("IRP_MJ_CREATE"));
            break;

        case IRP_MJ_CLOSE:
            KdPrint(("IRP_MJ_CLOSE"));
            break;

        default:
            Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
            break;
    }
    break;
}
nt_status = Irp->IoStatus.Status;
IoCompleteRequest (Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
return nt_status;
}
```

The relevant case is `case 0xF0:` inside `case IOCTL_TEST_READPORT:`

Comment: Can you show us the code for your IOCTL and locking pages? You could possibly calculate some of the sizes wrong. What is the memory address that causes BSOD and the locked buffer's start address? This is to see whether the first element causes BSOD or somewhere in the middle and to see if it's on some boundary

Comment: In any case (if this is your driver), the driver should verify addresses and buffers passed from a user program to not trigger a page fault.

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted doesn't show where you use that `malloc`ed buffer you spoke about earlier.  It only shows that you are getting a virtual address for a MDL so you can pass that pointer to `READ_PORT_BUFFER_USHORT`. This looks correct, AFAIK.

Comment: From the new data gotten from a comment on my answer, it seems you're missing some essential information in your question to be able to satisfactorily get the cause of your error.  Please provide more information, if you're still having this problem.

Comment: @Tony The Lion
I do the malloc in the user program, just before calling the function in a dll where I use DeviceIoControl function with my IOCTL and the pointer to the buffer I've just allocated (using METHOD_OUT_DIRECT). As I've said before, if this buffer is a normal array (for example: WORD buffer[256];) the driver never crashes and always runs correctly. If instead I declare the buffer using WORD *buffer = new WORD[256]; or WORD *buffer=(WORD*) malloc(sizeof(*buffer)*256)), then it is likely that I'll get a BSOD due to the crash of the driver with the error "page fault in non-paged area"

Comment: switch (current_port.size) case **0xF0**: READ_PORT_BUFFER_USHORT((PUSHORT)(USHORT)current_port.address, (PUSHORT)p_buffer, **256**) Why do you read 256 if you current_port.size=240

Comment: @sergmat
Because I use the field size of the structure current_port just to tell the driver what I want him to do. So I've decided to use F0 to make the driver return in my buffer 256 words. I could have called that case AA or 99 or in another way. (yes, it's a bit misleading!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are misunderstanding the purpose of `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe`.  [Per this document here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3ai3FRelP1tJwJ%3adownload.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/mem-mgmt.doc+windows+Memory+descriptor+list&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh2ZFm1eYLcVhKdyww6x0_JPA1u3HGrcED2DdZ6U_fKqVstz_XtmEhpfTW_Mzt0--t12KTCmmJMu_CKNspXqpqFWdqRnESlGyL6ufTHnYPu--ZiRLRjGIeAF0JQq_HLKYonDZ_7&sig=AHIEtbRvkjuRvrbgOcJia6X_Dt6LbwqrEA), you use this function to get virtual addresses that are described by a MDL (Memory Descriptor List).

> . If the driver must use virtual addresses to access the pages described by the MDL, it must map those pages into the system address space using MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe

that same document also says this:

> To use virtual addresses to access the buffer described by the MDL, the driver calls MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe to map the buffer into system space.
>
> **MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe**:
>   Maps the physical pages described by an MDL into system space and returns a virtual address for the MDL. The returned virtual address can be used **at any IRQL and in any process context.**

If you look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff554559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` then you will see this following line:

> The MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe macro returns a nonpaged system-space virtual address for the buffer that the specified MDL describes.

It says that this functions returns a **non-paged** virtual address for a buffer that is described by an MDL.

The definition of MDL is the following:

> A memory descriptor list (MDL) describes a list of pages in **physical memory**.

This is a description of pages in physical memory, not virtual memory.  Your buffer allocated by `new` will have virtual addresses already, trying to use `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` on it, is wrong.  You should use that function to get a virtual address from an MDL, not a MDL from a virtual address range.

Now, moving on to an explanation for the `page fault in non-paged area`:

Now if  you think about it, it is likely that your buffer allocated by `new` or `malloc` is already in a paged memory area (in fact, seeing that it's in user land, it's extremely likely), meaning that trying to get a virtual address to this buffer (which is already wrong because it's not an MDL), will cause a *page fault in non-paged area*, because the memory of the buffer is in a paged area, whereas you're mapping it to a non-paged area in the kernel, and non-paged areas can not cause a page fault.  (most likely will have to do with wrong IRQL levels)

Comment: I'm have a basic understanding of drivers only, but I think that physical memory = paged. Non-paged = currently removed from physical memory (for instance, to pagefile).

Comment: @Codeguard: No, it's more like this: "The nonpaged pool consists of virtual memory addresses that are guaranteed to reside in physical memory as long as the corresponding kernel objects are allocated. The paged pool consists of virtual memory that can be paged in and out of the system." [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa965226(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's where "locked" comes in.

Comment: Ok, I now think you were right. Searching for 'locked', in the same MSDN article for MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe, it says:

"On entry to this routine, the specified MDL must describe physical pages that are locked down. A locked-down MDL can be built by using the MmProbeAndLockPages, MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool, IoBuildPartialMdl, or MmAllocatePagesForMdlEx routine"

Still, it's unclear how the question author did it.

Comment: I understand non-paged memory as memory that can't be paged out. If it can be paged out, it can generate page faults and you'll get that error that OP got, meaning it's not in the non-paged pool.

Comment: Still, a LOCKED paged can't go away.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but I'm not sure what it is you're getting at?

Comment: So, should I use 
MmProbeAndLockPages(Irp->MdlAddress, UserMode, IoWriteAccess) 
before 
PVOID p_buffer = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Irp->MdlAddress, HighPagePriority)
?

Comment: @Jubba, yes, that seems to be what's needed, because the `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` doesn't lock the pages, and if they are non-resident then it can't map them, and seeing it maps them to nonpaged pool, they should be locked.

Comment: If the transfer type is `METHOD_OUT_DIRECT`, the system checks the address and size of the buffer. If these are valid, the system builds an MDL that describes the physical pages that comprise the buffer, and then it locks (or “pins”) those pages in physical memory. [User-Mode Interactions: Guidelines for Kernel-Mode Drivers. Mapped Memory Buffers](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oh4AQmy-WqEJ:download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/KM-UMGuide.doc+windows+kernel+mode+notifications&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=opera)

Comment: @sergmat
If the pages are already locked, then I do the right steps and it does not explain why I keep getting those crashes if I use a dynamically allocated buffer (malloc, new) while if I use a normal array it works...

Comment: @Jubba that's what I meant with my comment about needing more info.  The data you've given doesn't give any room for explanation as to what's causing the error. You need to give use what's happening before and after you're doing all this.

Comment: @Jubba analysis of the crash dump file may explain it